# Using external SMTP for relay in Exchange Server 2013?

Tags: exchange-2013

I've setup an Exchnage 2013 server. Internal emails are flowing fine. But there's some problem with external emails. Whenever I send emails to external domain I get the message that my IP is not authorized to send the emails directly and that I should relay to some other SMTP server. Hence I created a custom connector with smart host and used GoDaddy's smtp server address for the same. Still, whenever I send emails, my public IP is shown to the receipient and it refuses the email. What could be the solution?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your own external IP address will always be shown on the headers, there is nothing you can do to stop that. It is put on the headers by the next server. 
However unless the recipient is being very strict and checking all addresses within the header, it shouldn't be a problem.

Are you sure the emails are going via GoDaddy? Does your ISP not have an SMTP server that you can use? That is the usual route if you are on a dynamic IP address.

If you are on a static IP address, then get your ISP to set a PTR (aka reverse DNS record) on the address to match the A record, and configure the Send Connector with the correct FQDN. Also check to see if your static address is listed on any blacklists.

Comment: Yes, apparently the IP is in spamhaus blocklist (PBL).
I'm hosting the mail server at mail.company.com. So,should I ask the ISP to match its A record to the above address? Or is it fine if I do so in GoDaddy panel? Also, the FQDN will be mail.company.com, right?

Comment: That is one of the dynamic IP address blacklists.
You can ask your ISP to change the PTR, they may let you, they may not. You should check before you change any other DNS records. 
The FQDN, A record and PTR should be the same - so mail.example.com.

Comment: There are few DNS records already set in GoDaddy's panel including A, CNAME and MX which point to the static IP. Will it be a problem?

Comment: What you have at GoDaddy makes no difference. Your ISP needs to do the PTR, which needs to match one of those records. You then set the same host name as the FQDN on the Send Connector.

Comment: Although the ISP (still) has no PTR to my domain, I'm now able to receive emails. That happened right after I set MX entry for my server with godaddy with 0 priority. I've only messed up quotes for my SPF record...lol, will fix that I guess it will start sending emails too.
Btw, my ISP is on 5th position of top 20 spam hosters by uceprotect.

Comment: PTR has nothing to do with inbound email, it is just to allow you to send email directly, so outbound email. However if your ISP is well known as a home of spammers, then you are going to have to use a smart host to get reliable email, whether GoDaddy or a commercial provider.

Comment: Yes exactly. My ISP in on no. 5 in top 20 spamhoster by uceprotect. So I guess I will need to get PTR set from them. What is the other option? I've used sendgrid's smtp but it too apparently holding the emails because the ip is blacklisted(?)